# Convert Float to Int in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, type-conversion

I want to convert a `Float` to an `Int` in Swift. Basic casting like this does not work because these types are not primitives, unlike `float`s and `int`s in Objective-C

```
var float: Float = 2.2
var integer: Int = float as Float
```

But this produces the following error message:

> 'Float' is not convertible to 'Int'

Any idea how to property convert from `Float` to `Int`?

Comment: the `as` operator is for down-casting to subclasses. ie: `UIView as UIButton`

Comment: in swift, you can do type casting using the as keyword or optional as (as?) such as 4 as? String, if 4 can be a string it will work but if it's not it will not work. I bring this up because you use the word "casting" in your question and i didn't want you to be confused. :3

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. (float as Float) does nothing because float is of type Float already. You either meant var integer: Int = float (same error) or var integer: Int = float as Int.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

You can convert `Float` to `Int` in Swift like this:

```
var myIntValue:Int = Int(myFloatValue)
println "My value is \(myIntValue)"
```

You can also achieve this result with @paulm's comment:

```
var myIntValue = Int(myFloatValue)
```

Comment: @paulm - I had not tried *(above code in comment)*. but might be it will work for us *(not sure)*.

Comment: The cast is enough for the Swift compiler to intuit the variable type, so you do not need to explicitly declare the type. `var myIntValue = Int(myFloatValue)` works.

Comment: (swift 2.0) it's better to check if the float value is a finite value, if myFloatvalue.isFinite {...}

Comment: This code will crash for large values like `Int(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)`.

Answer (score 136):

### Explicit Conversion

Converting to Int will lose any precision (effectively rounding down). By accessing the math libraries you can perform explicit conversions. For example:

If you wanted to **round down** and convert to integer:

```
let f = 10.51
let y = Int(floor(f))
```

result is 10.

If you wanted to **round up** and convert to integer:

```
let f = 10.51
let y = Int(ceil(f))
```

result is 11.

If you want to *explicitly* **round to the nearest integer**

```
let f = 10.51
let y = Int(round(f))
```

result is 11.

In the latter case, this might seem pedantic, but it's semantically clearer as there is no implicit conversion...important if you're doing signal processing for example.

Comment: Yeah, it's really worth noting that **Int()** simply cuts the fractional part, which usually isn't the desired behaviour ;) **Int(round(f))** does the job.

Comment: Or ceil ()to round the value upwards.

Comment: Edge case: `round(10.5) == 11.0`

Comment: `let y = Int(round(f))` can also be written as `let y = lround(f)`

Answer (score 35):

There are lots of ways to round number with precision. You should eventually use swift's standard library method `rounded()` to round float number with desired precision.

To round **up** use `.up` rule:

```
let f: Float = 2.2
let i = Int(f.rounded(.up)) // 3
```

To round **down** use `.down` rule:

```
let f: Float = 2.2
let i = Int(f.rounded(.down)) // 2
```

To round to the **nearest** integer use `.toNearestOrEven` rule:

```
let f: Float = 2.2
let i = Int(f.rounded(.toNearestOrEven)) // 2
```

Be aware of the following example:

```
let f: Float = 2.5
let i = Int(roundf(f)) // 3
let j = Int(f.rounded(.toNearestOrEven)) // 2
```

Comment: This should be the best answer, since it raises the awareness of rounding and its related API, so that the developer can take more control and responsibility.

[`FloatingPointRoundingRule`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpointroundingrule)

Answer (score 29):

Converting is simple:

```
let float = Float(1.1) // 1.1
let int = Int(float) // 1
```

But it is not safe:

```
let float = Float(Int.max) + 1
let int = Int(float)
```

Will due to a nice crash:

```
fatal error: floating point value can not be converted to Int because it is greater than Int.max
```

So I've created an extension that handles overflow:

```
extension Double {
    // If you don't want your code crash on each overflow, use this function that operates on optionals
    // E.g.: Int(Double(Int.max) + 1) will crash:
    // fatal error: floating point value can not be converted to Int because it is greater than Int.max
    func toInt() -> Int? {
        if self > Double(Int.min) && self < Double(Int.max) {
            return Int(self)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}


extension Float {
    func toInt() -> Int? {
        if self > Float(Int.min) && self < Float(Int.max) {
            return Int(self)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this can help someone

Answer (score 7):

You can get an integer representation of your float by passing the float into the Integer initializer method.

Example:

```
Int(myFloat)
```

Keep in mind, that any numbers after the decimal point will be loss. Meaning, 3.9 is an Int of 3 and 8.99999 is an integer of 8.

Comment: And use Int(MyFloat + .5) for rounding.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
var float:Float = 2.2 // 2.2
var integer:Int = Int(float) // 2 .. will always round down.  3.9 will be 3
var anotherFloat: Float = Float(integer) // 2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a function style conversion (found in section labeled "Integer and Floating-Point Conversion" from "[The Swift Programming Language.](https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l)"[iTunes link])

```
  1> Int(3.4)
$R1: Int = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can type cast like this:

```
 var float:Float = 2.2
 var integer:Int = Int(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use type casting

```
 var floatValue:Float = 5.4
 var integerValue:Int = Int(floatValue)

 println("IntegerValue = \(integerValue)")
```

it will show roundoff value eg: IntegerValue = 5 means the decimal point will be loss

Answer (score 1):

```
var floatValue = 10.23
var intValue = Int(floatValue)
```

This is enough to convert from `float` to `Int`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you store float value in `"X"` and you are storing integer value in `"Y"`.

```
Var Y = Int(x);
```

or

```
var myIntValue = Int(myFloatValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1 as Int

var cgf = CGFLoat(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions presented here would crash for large values and should *not* be used in production code.

If you don't care for very large values use this code to clamp the `Double` to max/min `Int` values.

```
let bigFloat   = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
let smallFloat = -bigFloat

extension Float {
    func toIntTruncated() -> Int {
        let maxTruncated  = min(self, Float(Int.max).nextDown)
        let bothTruncated = max(maxTruncated, Float(Int.min))
        return Int(bothTruncated)
    }
}

// This crashes:
// let bigInt = Int(bigFloat)

// this works for values up to 9223371487098961920
let bigInt   = bigFloat.toIntTruncated()
let smallInt = smallFloat.toIntTruncated()
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can make a handy extension using computed property and use it from any where in project

```
    extension Float{
    
    var toInt : Int{
       return Int(self)
    }
    
}
```

> Calling

```
private var call: Float = 55.9
print(call.toInt)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Int64` instead of `Int`. `Int64` can store large int values.

Comment: you mean, for the original question, or for the problem with `Float` having a value range larger than `Int` ?