# Swift conversions, CGFloat to Integer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, integer, cgfloat

How do you convert a @IValue CGFloat to an Int?

I keep getting a `cannot convert @IValue CGFloat to Integer` with the following:

```
@IBOutlet var userObject : UIImageView


func returnYPosition(yPosition: Integer) -> Integer {
    return userObject.center.y
}
```

Comment: Integer has been renamed to IntegerType.  But I think you might be trying to return an Int not an IntegerType.  So change the signature to func returnYPosition(yPosition: Int)->Int, etc.

Comment: A good solution can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029917/convert-float-to-int-in-swift

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work finally! Yeah, I was trying to get an Int, idk what I had it as Integer haha @user1790252

Comment: This helped me finally figure out how to change the type of variable! Thanks! @MinnesotaSteve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `Int` types back and forth, and then just cast:

```
func returnYPosition(yPosition: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(userObject.center.y)
}
```