# CGFloat not converting to UInt32?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

Usually this works fine for me, but for some reason I am getting the error "Cannot assign a value of type 'CGFloat' to a value of type 'Int'" right now. I am simply trying to take my randomly generated integer and turn it into a CGFloat. However, it appears the code `UInt32(self.view!.frame.width - dotRadius * 2)` is generating an error.  Here is the code:

```
    x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view!.frame.width - dotRadius * 2))) + dotRadius
```

Here is where I declare the dotRadius variable:

```
var dotRadius: CGFloat = 0
```

Anyone know why I'm not allowed to convert that? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The error-message is not saying that you can't convert an integer to a CGFloat, but rather the reverse. So it's presumably complaining about the `UInt32(...)` part (not the `CGFloat(...)` part, which is fine).

Comment: how is dotRadius declared?

Comment: @ruakh you are correct. How would I go about converting that part then? the_pantless_coder it is a CGFloat I declared earlier

Comment: maybe I am missing something, but I dont get any errors with "            var dotRadus:CGFloat = 666
                 var x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view!.frame.width - dotRadus * 2))) + dotRadus"

Comment: My guess is that `dotRadius` is an integer type when it should be `CGFloat`.

Comment: @Arrku, thats what I am thinking. I also tried "            let dotRadus:Int = 666
            let x = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view!.frame.width - CGFloat(dotRadus) * 2))) + CGFloat(dotRadus)
        " with no errors

Comment: @the_paintless_coder I put in the original question how I declare the dotRadius variable. It is already a CGFloat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CGFloat(...)` part is fine; the error-message isn't saying that you can't *explicitly* convert an integer *to* a CGFloat, but rather, that you can't *implicitly* convert *from* a CGFloat to an Int. More specifically, I think it's complaining because of the final assignment `x = ...`; the part on the right is a CGFloat, and I'm guessing that `x` is an Int?

If so, then you should be able to fix this by adding an explicit cast from CGFloat to Int:

```
x = Int(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view!.frame.width - dotRadius * 2))) + dotRadius)
```

[This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467208/978917) suggests that you also include an explicit `floor` or `round` (from the math libraries) before casting to `Int`, to make it clear what kind of rounding you expect.

Comment: Tried with that exact code and it still isn't working. I also tried using a floor function, with no effect. Strange part is I was using code VERY similar to this earlier and it worked fine...

Comment: @Kendel: Wait, I'm being silly. What it's really complaining about is probably the assignment at the very end; `x` is probably declared as `Int`?

Comment: Wow. Yep that is correct. Forgot that x is declared as `Int` Thanks for the help!