# Convert string (float value) to int in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

Hello I have string "(with `float` value)"

```
let floatstring : String = "23.24" 
print(floatstring)
```

I want to convert float `String` to `Int`.
Thank you !

Comment: `print(Int(Float(floatstring)!))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
let intNum = Int(Float(floatstring)!)
```

**Option 2**

```
if floatstring.rangeOfString(".") != nil {
    let i = Int(floatstring.componentsSeparatedByString(".").first!)
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It should work like this:

http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57bd6566b36620d114f80313

```
let floatstring : String = "23.24" 
print(Int(Float(floatstring)!))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the String to a Float and then to an Int.

```
if let floatValue = Float(floatString) {
    if let intValue = Int(floatValue) {
        print(intValue) //that is your Int
    }
}
```

If it does not print anything then the string is not a 'floatString'.
Btw you can simply find the answer by combining the answers to these Questions.

[Stackoverflow: String to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019236/get-integer-value-from-string-in-swift)

[Stackoverflow: Casting Float to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029917/convert-float-to-int-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

1.For Swift 2.0

```
let intValue=int(float(floatString))
```

2.For Older version of Swift

```
let floatValue = (floatString.text as NSString).floatValue
let intValue:Int? = Int(floatValue)
```

3.For objective-C

```
floatValue = [floatString floatValue];
int intValue:Int = (int) floatValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
let floatValue = "23.24".floatValue  // first convert string to float
let intValue:Int? = Int(floatValue)  // then convert float to int 
print(intValue!)
```