# Swift 3:fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN

Tags: swift

When I call this method, an error received. How to handle NaN or infinite  value during assign to hour, min or sec?

Here is my code:

```
private func secondsToFormattedString(totalSeconds: Float64) -> String{
    let hours:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 86400) / 3600)

    let minutes:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60)
    let seconds:Int = Int(totalSeconds.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))

    if hours > 0 {
        return String(format: "%i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    } else {
        return String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider to use `TimeInterval` and `DateComponentsFormatter`

Comment: How do you call the function and what is the value of totalSeconds when the problem occurs? – A self-contained, reproducible test case would be helpful.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should check if `totalSeconds` is a valid value, like:

```
guard !(totalsSeconds.isNaN || totalSeconds.isInfinite) else {
    return "illegal value" // or do some error handling
}
```

And check this:
[Convert Float to Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029917/convert-float-to-int-in-swift)

Comment: Neither a nan or infinity is finite, so you could just say `guard totalSeconds.isFinite else {...}`.

Comment: @Hamish You're definitly correct. I just wanted to point out the different APIs, because the original Question explicitly mentioned NaN and Infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a formatter for this, I just wanted to convert a Double to an Int to make it easier to display in my UI so a `NumberFormatter` was perfect, my Double was NaN so that's what the `NumberFormatter` provided me, rather than the `fatalError` that the Int 'cast' provided (why doesn't it return an optional like Int(String) does?)

But in the context of this question a `DateFormatter` is a great solution, which would do the whole function's work for you (bear in mind that creating `DateFormatter`s is a little costly so you wouldn't want to create one for every string formatting you do but keep it hanging out if it makes sense)