# AVPlayer - Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have this function:

```
func getSeconds()->Int{
        
        return Int(Double(self.value) * (self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds)!)
    }
```

It sometimes crashes:

> Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN

Of course I've seen this:

[Swift 3:fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000061/swift-3fatal-error-double-value-cannot-be-converted-to-int-because-it-is-eithe)

But how EXACTLY do I have to use this?

What is this?:

```
guard !(totalSeconds.isNaN || totalSeconds.isInfinite) else {
    return "illegal value"
}
```

Where do I `return totalSeconds` if everything is fine?

**EDIT:**

I'm doing it like this now:

```
func getSeconds()->Int{
    
    let totalSeconds = self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds
    
    if(totalSeconds != nil){
        guard !(totalSeconds!.isNaN || totalSeconds!.isInfinite) else {
            return 0 // or do some error handling
        }
        
        return Int(Double(self.value) * (self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds)!)
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Int does not have those fields afaik, they are for Float and Double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer to the question you linked to, the code is there to verify that the value is a valid number.

Your edit is in the correct direction but it could use some improvements to the handling of optionals. Something like the following might be better:

```
func getSeconds() -> Int {   
    guard let totalSeconds = self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds,
        !totalSeconds.isNaN && !totalSeconds.isInfinite else { return 0 }
    
    return Int(Double(self.value) * totalSeconds)
}
```

The `guard` first gets the value of `self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds` but only if there is a non-optional value. If `self.player.currentItem` is currently nil then there won't be a duration.

Once the `guard` gets a value in seconds, it makes sure the value is neither NaN nor infinite.

So the `guard`'s `else` will be reached if there is no current item to get the duration for, or if the duration isn't a finite number.

If you have a good number, the code can move on the calculation and return a final value.

Note there is no use of force-unwraps in the code. You should avoid those to eliminate likely crashes. Learning proper optional handling in Swift is critical.

As stated in a comment to the answer you referenced, the whole `!(totalSeconds.isNaN || totalSeconds.isInfinite)` can be written as `totalSeconds.isFinite`. Doing that in your function would change the `guard` to be:

```
guard let totalSeconds = self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds,
    totalSeconds.isFinite else { return 0 }
```

This is a bit easier to read and more to the point of the needed check in this case.

Comment: Something else to consider is that your `getSeconds` method should probably return an optional `Int` (`Int?`) instead of `0` in the case where the guard fails. But that's a discussion beyond your original question.